# Overlay Street View with GIS layers

Tags: layers, google-earth, vector-layer, display, google-street-view

I am wondering about the option, which would allow a user to overlay the Street View with various GIS layers produced by the following files: AutoCAD DXF (or even DWG), Shapefile, GeoJson, KML, and so on.
So far I've found, that a bit of the described possibility is available on Google Earth like shown below:
[image]
where by creating the object (polygon or line/point) and setting it "Relative to ground" and "Extending sides to ground" we are able to spot this element on the Street View scene.
Unfortunately, it applies just to objects created on Google Earth. It doesn't work for imported KML files with further edits applied (altitude + extension to the ground). I am looking for the option of overlay Street View with various GIS layers, which would participate along the scene in the same way as they appear in OpenStreetMap, etc.
Does anyone know if is it possible at all? Where should I find some information, or maybe some programming sources for this purpose?

Comment: Is there any further progress with this question? The topic is similarly related to this (e.g. overlaying shapes onto photo collections): https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/454917/automatically-plotting-linestring-flight-path-trajectories-onto-photos-of-the-sk

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This does not seem possible at the moment out of the box,
From the [google maps JS API street view documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/streetview#StreetViewOverlays):

`"Currently, the types of overlays which are supported on Street View panoramas are limited to Markers, InfoWindows and custom OverlayViews"`

You might be able to implement displaying something more complex than a Marker or InfoWindow if you create your own type of [`customOverlayView`](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/overlay-view#OverlayView).
But, the [only example](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/overlay-simple) they have for custom overlayView is using a georeferenced raster map, so I'm not sure how that could be implemented for 3D objects. Writing something like that might warrant a more focused question.