# Automatically plotting linestring flight path trajectories onto photos of the sky

Tags: geopandas, overlay, trajectories

Can anyone suggest how we would lay linestring flight tracks on a terrestial sky image (see below).

[image]

The flight tracks are as geopandas linestrings. We want to do this for thousands of images.

Answer (score 2):

So what you are trying to do automatically is going to be quite hard, or even impossible to do, depending on what information you have.

And you will need to use more tools than geopandas - consider maybe doing this in Blender with a custom python script (you will need to convert the geopandas linestrings to 3D mesh objects though)

You of course need the flight paths including elevation and additionally you are going to need two more metadata entries from the camera:

- The focal length (easy, that should be included)
- The angle of the camera view over the horizon (pitch)

With that you *might* be able to:

- Place the flight paths into a three dimensional system
- Get the camera location (X, Y, Z) and rotation (Z and X (pitch)) and place a camera with those attributes in the system

Now you should in theory be able to set the field of view according to the focal length and adjust the image ration to fit the original image.

If everything is done right you should now be able to see the lines in the viewfinder aligned with the trails of the aircrafts. In order to have them be  of equal width in the render consider projecting them from the origin of the camera onto a plane and then increase the width as necessary.

However, a lot of things need to go right here and I am also quite sure that this is not the most practical approach.